# Telerik Extensions for ASP.NET MVC - Performance Implications

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, telerik

I've used quite a bit of the Telerik RadControls for AJAX, and though I've been pretty happy with the controls, I've found that the performance has been less than stellar over traditional controls.

I'm wondering what the performance implications would be (that you might know of) with regards to the MVC Extensions over traditional jQuery libraries (Telerik MVC Grid VS jqGrid for example).

Basically, how well does Telerik MVC Extensions perform?

***on a side note***: does the Telerik MVC Extensions grab a copy of the jQuery library to use, or am I responsible for adding it to my page for it to work?  I'd be a happy guy if I'm the one that has to do this instead of the extensions doing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First I need to put some disclaimer as I am one of the developers of Telerik Extensions for ASP.NET MVC. My opinion is obviously biased :)

What are your requirements? How many rows do you intend to show in the grid? How many records do you have in the database? I have tested the grid with 100k db records and 10 items per page. Performance was very good.

By default the extensions include jQuery-1.4.2.min.js but you can prevent this and include it yourself:

```
<%= Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar().jQuery(false) %>
```

Comment: this is great that I can exclude jQuery. are their other default scripts that also need to/can be excluded?

Comment: The rest of the scripts are the built-in ones.

Answer (score 0):

Displaying < 100 rows, which I consider a pretty usable grid size, is probably pretty fast using any Javascript grid.  I'd say your bottle neck will be data access unless your trying to display 100,000 rows of data.

The example here, http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/Grid?theme=vista, has > 8300 records and is pretty snappy.